# How to count with condition in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a table with events from  1 to 11, The variables have 3 kinds of charcters like HSP,REP,OH. I need to count HSP by creating a new columns as  OH1,OH2,OH3,OH4. The description of each column is

1) Number Of HSP before first OH
2) Number of HSP between 1st and 2nd OH
3) Number of HSP between 2nd and 3rd OH
4) Number of HSP between 3rd and 4th OH

```
SLN     EV1 EV2 EV3 EV4 EV5 EV6 EV7 EV8 EV9 EV10 EV11
120132  HSP OH  HSP HSP REP OH  HSP HSP HSP OH  REP
120135  OH  HSP HSP HSP HSP OH  HSP HSP HSP HSP OH
120200  OH  HSP OH  HSP HSP OH  HSP OH  HSP OH  HSP
120251  OH  HSP 
120318  HSP OH  HSP HSP HSP OH  HSP HSP HSP HSP HSP
120327  OH  HSP HSP HSP HSP OH  HSP HSP HSP HSP HSP
120509  HSP OH  HSP HSP HSP HSP OH  HSP HSP OH  HSP
120510  HSP HSP
```

if there is no following 'OH' at all then set to missing E.g.120327: oh1=0, oh2=4, oh3=.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
data want;
  set have;
  x1=cat(of ev1-ev11);
  x2=' '||tranwrd(x1,'OH','|');
  array oh oh1-oh4;
  if index(x2,'|') then
  do i = 1 to 4;
    oh[i]=count(scan(x2,i,'|'),'HSP');
  end;
  else call missing(of oh1-oh4);
  drop x1-x2 i;
run;
```

`x1` concatenates the codes into a long string. `x2` adds pipes which makes the scan function in the oh calculations possible, it also adds a space at the front to allow `oh1` to equal zero if the first code is `'OH'`

You could use arrays or macros if you need to extend this beyond the 11 `ev` columns and 4 `OH` counts.

Edit: Added array for the `OH` count.

Edited to set nulls if no `OH` found.

### REVISED

```
data counts;
input SLN EV1 $ EV2 $ EV3 $ EV4 $ EV5 $ EV6 $ EV7 $ EV8 $ EV9 $ EV10 $ EV11 $;
array EV[11] ;
array OH[4];
chk=0;
next = 1;
do i=1 to 4;
    oh[i] = 0;
end;
do i=1 to 11;
    if next > 4 then leave;
    if ev[i] = "HSP" then
        OH[next] = OH[next] + 1;
    else if ev[i] = "OH" then do;
        next = next + 1;
            chk+1;
        end;
    end;
    if chk<4 then do j=chk+1 to 4;
      oh[j]=.;
    end;



datalines;
120132  HSP OH  HSP HSP REP OH  HSP HSP HSP OH  REP
120135  OH  HSP HSP HSP HSP OH  HSP HSP HSP HSP OH
120200  OH  HSP OH  HSP HSP OH  HSP OH  HSP OH  HSP
120251  OH  HSP REP HSP REP HSP HSP HSP HSP OH  HSP
120318  HSP OH  HSP HSP HSP OH  HSP HSP HSP HSP HSP
120327  OH  HSP HSP HSP HSP OH  HSP HSP HSP HSP HSP
120509  HSP OH  HSP HSP HSP HSP OH  HSP HSP OH  HSP
120510  HSP OH  HSP REP HSP HSP OH  HSP HSP HSP HSP
;
run;
```

Comment: Nice, But if the SN has only one event EV1 with HSP it outputs OH1 as 1 and EV1 & EV2 has HSP HSP and EV3 has no OH, Then also it outputs as OH1 is 2. But I want to output if there is no OH after HSP, The output should be null

Comment: The amended version now checks if there is an 'OH' at all and then does the counts. If there isn't it just sets all the OH count variables to missing.

Comment: Hi mjsqu, I used the same code but oh1-oh4 going null irrespective of condition.

Comment: Sorry, the index should contain `'|'` not `'OH'`

Comment: Sorry, Its working only where the events have no OH, But in the case of ev1:HSP, ev2:OH, ev3:HSP, Its counting HSP after ev2:OH in to output of OH2. If there is HSP-OH-HSP then Iwant output of OH1=1, OH2=0, OH3=0, OH4=0.

Comment: Oh, so if there is no following 'OH' at all then set to missing? E.g. do you want this for `120327`: ev1=0, ev2=4, ev3=.      Whereas my code gives ev3=5?

Comment: Yes mjsqu, Thats what I want

Comment: I've edited the @DomPazz answer as it was easier using his logic. You'll need to wait until (s)he's checked it.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt. If I use DomPazz code after edited by you will it work as I desire? Still your edited code of DomPazz is not reflecting.

Comment: Yes, I've just revised my answer so you don't need to wait. If you have an input dataset, remove the `datalines` bit and the input statement at the top. Put your `set` statement before `chk=0;`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way using arrays and without doing string concatination and parsing

```
data counts;
input SLN EV1 $ EV2 $ EV3 $ EV4 $ EV5 $ EV6 $ EV7 $ EV8 $ EV9 $ EV10 $ EV11 $;
array EV[11] ;
array OH[4];

next = 1;
do i=1 to 4;
    oh[i] = 0;
end;
do i=1 to 11;
    if next > 4 then leave;
    if ev[i] = "HSP" then
        OH[next] = OH[next] + 1;
    else if ev[i] = "OH" then
        next = next + 1;
end;

datalines;
120132  HSP OH  HSP HSP REP OH  HSP HSP HSP OH  REP
120135  OH  HSP HSP HSP HSP OH  HSP HSP HSP HSP OH
120200  OH  HSP OH  HSP HSP OH  HSP OH  HSP OH  HSP
120251  OH  HSP REP HSP REP HSP HSP HSP HSP OH  HSP
120318  HSP OH  HSP HSP HSP OH  HSP HSP HSP HSP HSP
120327  OH  HSP HSP HSP HSP OH  HSP HSP HSP HSP HSP
120509  HSP OH  HSP HSP HSP HSP OH  HSP HSP OH  HSP
120510  HSP OH  HSP REP HSP HSP OH  HSP HSP HSP HSP
;
run;
```

Comment: Great answer, I knew there would be a better way to do it!

Comment: Nice, But if the SN has only one event EV1 with HSP it outputs OH1 as 1 and EV1 & EV2 has HSP HSP and EV3 has no OH, Then also it outputs as OH1 is 2. But I want to output if there is no OH after HSP, The output should be null.

Comment: To update this version for your requirements takes a bit more work. Change this `else if ev[i] = "OH" then` to a `then do;` block and increment a variable by using e.g. `chk+1;`. Then after the `do i=1 to 11;` block finishes, check if the `chk` value is zero and set the `oh1-oh4` variables to missing. I hope I've explained that OK, perhaps @DomPazz has a better way anyway...